# What is the proper way to implement selection and highlight animations on UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am trying to code a `UITableViewCell` with a custom animation for both selection and highlight states. I have overridden the `setSelected:animated:` and `setHighlighted:animated:` methods. However, these two methods are always called with `animated:false`. Therefore, I am unable to determine whether the methods are being invoked by the system (when the table view clears selections) or when the user taps. Now, for the highlight, I could probably just assume that it is always invoked by the user since I didn't find any other way to only highlight a cell programatically. For `setSelected:animated:`, I must know whether to animate or not. At first, I couldn't find what is calling `setSelected:animated:` in the first place when I tap on the cell because even after overriding every `UITableViewDelegate` method without calling `super`, `setSelected:animated:` was getting called from somewhere.

After searching for days, I disassembled the `UIKitCore.framework` using hopper disassembler and found out that `setSelected:animated:` is actually called by `touchesEnded:event:` method. There is actually an internal `setSelected:` method which calls `setSelected:animated:` with `false` by default. Moreover, since there is no documented api which lets you only highlight a cell (without selection) and internally, `setHighlighted:animated:` is always called with `false`, so what is the purpose of having an `animated` argument in this method's signature?

I have found not a whole lot of examples on this. Whatever I have found involves calling `tableView.select:rowAtIndexPath:animated` with `animated:true` manually in may be `didSelectRow` or `willSelectRow`. That feels hacky because it calls `setSelected:animated:` twice.

I am sure that I am not the first one to implement custom animations for highlight and selection for the UITableViewCell.

### Update:

This is what I have implemented so far and it works even though it feels hacky.

```swift
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    guard isSelected != selected else {
        return
    }
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if animated {...}
}

// how can I call animated with true?
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    guard isHighlighted != highlighted else {
        return
    }
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    if animated {...}
}


// overriding the touch handlers doesn't feel right.
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    setHighlighted(true, animated: true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    setHighlighted(false, animated: true)
    setSelected(!isSelected, animated: true)
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    setHighlighted(false, animated: true)
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: Why downvote with no explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I had an image in different cells in a collectionview once.

```
    let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "icon1")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    iv.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 91, green: 14, blue: 13)
    return iv
}()
// Highlighted when pressed
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.white : UIColor.rgb(red: 91, green: 14, blue: 13)
    }
}
// When selected
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.rgb(red: 91, green: 14, blue: 13)
    }
}
```

Maybe that gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. This will work in cases where I don’t want to animate the transition. I need to solve for cases where I want to animate based on the animated argument. The animated argument is always false when I tap on the row.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that there is really no API on `UITableView` to **highlight** the `UITableViewCell` programmatically like **selection**, unless you explicitly call `setHighlighted:animated:` on the cell instance with `animated:true`. I can confirm this after looking at the disassembled code for `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` using `Hopper`.

In general, both `setHighlighted:animated:` and `setSelected:animated:` are invoked with `animated:false` from `UIView` touch handlers. There are two internal API function `setHighlighted:` and `setAnimated:` which internally pass the `animated: false` similar to the following:

```
func setSelected(_ selected: Bool) {
    setSelected(selected, animated: false)
}

func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool) {
    setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: false)
}

func touches...(...) // the touch handlers {
    // setSelected(selected)
    // setHighlighted(highlighted) 
}
```

Overriding the touch handlers is not a proper solution because there are many other things happening the in the `super` implementation. If you skip them, it may corrupt the internal state of the cell. However, the moment you call `super.touchesBegan` or any other touch handler, the selection and highlight methods will be called with `animated: false`.

Moreover, from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) it seems that you are supposed to override all the touch handlers if you decide to override one.

> If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, even if your implementations do nothing.

### My Solution

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    return indexPath
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    return indexPath
}
```

You must return `indexPath` from these handlers as otherwise, the delegate methods will not be called. However, that means you will now call the `setSelected:animated:` twice. That can be prevented by using a `guard` as shown below.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    guard isSelected != selected else {
        return
    }
    if animated {}
}
```

To animate highlight, use the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    // there is no api on tableview to highlight the cell.
    // so you must invoke highlight directly on the cell.
    cell?.setHighlighted(true, animated: true)
    return true
}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    guard isHighlighted != highlighted else {
        return
    }
    if animated {}
}
```

However, this leaves one last hole, that is when `highlighted == false`, you wouldn't really know whether to animate it or not. You could keep a local variable in the cell to keep its track.